# Entity Framework linq query

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I need help formatting my link query properly, **I am using EF 3.5**:

```
Dim mediators = (From m In entity.Mediators _
                 Where m.MediatorAvailabilities.Available = "Weekends"
                         Where (m.isActive = True) _
                        Order By m.Sequence _
                        Select New RankingCriteria() With { _
                            .FirstName = m.FirstName, _
                            .LastName = m.LastName, _
                            .CompanyName = m.CompanyName, _
                            .PhoneHome = m.PhoneHome, _
                            .PhoneWork = m.PhoneWork, _
                            .PhoneMobile = m.PhoneMobile, _
                            .Email = m.Email _
                        }).ToList()
```

I have a navigation property in Mediators to MediatorAvailabilities I want to do something like what is in where clause above in order to filter my results. It's not letting me navigate to the appropriate column by doing this: m.MediatorAvailabilities.Available.

How do I do this filter properly?

Thanks, Justin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use the `Any` method. I dont know the proper VB syntax, but it should look something like this:

```
Where m.MediatorAvailabilities.Any(ma => ma.Available = "Weekends")
```

Comment: Thanks Aducci! Now thatI am headed in the right direction how would I grab all columns where "Available" is null? I have tried the following but in only brings back the rows where Available = "weekends" I want to also bring back the rows if Available is Null: Where (m.MediatorRestrictionsAvailabilities.Any(Function(a) a.Availability = String.Empty Or a.Availability.Contains("weekends") = True)) _

Comment: @Asmussen - I am not too sure what you are asking. It would  be best if you ask a new question.

Comment: Aducci, I posted a seperate post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017889/using-linq-to-entities-3-5-to-select-null-columns