# Using Linq to Entities 3.5 to select null columns

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-3.5

I am using **Entity Framework 3.5**. My model has a Mediator table and a MediatorAvailabilities table. Most Mediators do not have an entry in MediatorAvailabilities (Availability = Null) but I still need to bring back the mediator whether or not there is a related MediatorAvailabilities.

My query below is only bring back a mediator if there is a related Availability. Again how do I get mediators even if Availability = null?:

```
Dim mediators = (From m In entity.Mediators.Include("MediatorAvailabilities") _
Where(m.MediatorAvailabilities.Any(Function(a) a.Availability = String.Empty Or a.Availability.Contains("Weekends") = True))
                         Where (m.isActive = True) _
                        Order By m.Sequence _
                        Select New RankingCriteria() With { _
                            .FirstName = m.FirstName, _
                            .LastName = m.LastName, _
                            .CompanyName = m.CompanyName, _
                            .PhoneHome = m.PhoneHome, _
                            .PhoneWork = m.PhoneWork, _
                            .PhoneMobile = m.PhoneMobile, _
                            .Email = m.Email _
                        }).ToList()
```

What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add  `a.Availability is Nothing` in your `Any` method call like so:

```
Where(m.MediatorAvailabilities.Any(Function(a) a.Availability is Nothing Or a.Availability = String.Empty Or a.Availability.Contains("Weekends") = True))
```

Comment: Thanks again Aducci, I could not get "Is Nothing" to work. I ended up using m.MediatorAvailabilities.Count >= 0. I am not sure if this is the proper way but it seems to be working. Let me know if you have any other ideas.